# sending mail from mobile using cordova

Tags: javascript, email, cordova

We have a requirement to send mails on a submit button or event to the known recipient. 
We chose cordova for the app and included cordova.js and cordova_plugin.js. The API used is

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
```

where args is

```
var args = {
  subject: 'XYZ',
  body: 'PQR',
  toRecipients: '123@123.com'
};
```

But this does not result into sending any email.

Any leads/ pointers/ implementation of the requirement or the fix for the issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any mailto: link will open the device's email application. You could simply do this:

```
<a href="mailto:123@123.com?subject=XYZ &body=PQR">Submit email</a>
```